# Exception in not mapped inside flatMap

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-webflux, reactor

I have a piece of code that calls an external service. And  I wanted to map error from this service. I tried to do that this way:

```
public Mono<Void> patch(String userId, Payload payload) {
        return Mono.just(payload)
                .flatMap(it -> client.patch(userId, PatchRequest.buildRequest(payload, userId))
                        .onErrorMap(throwable -> GeneralActionException.ofFailedSetup()));
    }
```

But when I mocked the client to return RuntimeException

```
Mockito.when(client.patch(any(), any())).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
```

It turned out my test:

```
StepVerifier.create(sut.patch(userId, payload))
                .verifyError(GeneralActionException.class);
```

failed, because the returned error was RuntimeException:

However when I change the code a little, just like that:

```
public Mono<Void> patch(String userId, Payload payload) {
        return Mono.just(payload)
                .flatMap(it -> client.patch(userId, PatchRequest.buildRequest(payload, userId)))
                .onErrorMap(throwable -> GeneralActionException.ofFailedSetup());
}
```

It turned out the test succeeded. The question is why? Because I don't understand why it works differently in both cases and especially why in the first example when error mapping is inside `flatMap` it doesn't map it to `GeneralException`?

Comment: Add the full error screenshot for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. I mocked client wrongly.
Instead of:

```
Mockito.when(client.patch(any(), any())).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
```

it should be:

```
Mockito.when(client.patch(any(), any())).thenReturn(Mono.error(RuntimeException::new));
```

as the client returns `Mono<Void>`